# Placing a symbol with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would like to use the tree symbol from the `tikzsymbols` package. I am using the `\Summertree[3.38];` function in the Tikz environement (the 3.38 is the scale making the heigh of the tree equal to 1). But Tikz places the tree in a funny way and using `\Summertree[3.38];`, the basis of the tree is in x=0.58 and in y=0...

I would like to creat a `\arbre` command, so that my tree would have a heigh H, and its basis is at (x0,y0). Hence, in the preamble I wrote :

```
\newcommand{\arbre}[4] %x0 y0 H alpha
{
    \begin{scope}[rotate=#4,xshift=#1-0.587*#3,yshift=#2]
        \Summertree[3.38*#3];
    \end{scope}
}
```

In the Tikz environement I write `\arbre{0}{0}{1}{0};` wich gives exactly the smae output as `\Summertree[3.38];`, ignoring the shifts I requested. He the result of my plot (the bullet is at (0,0) where I want my tree to be planted.. I mean plotted).

[image: My tree still a position x0 = 0.58]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Summertree[]` actually output something like a character, so to use it properly in Ti*k*Z, you should use `node`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray,help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\path (0,0) node[above,inner sep=0pt] {\Summertree[3.38]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Starting from this, we can easily have your command `\arbre` as follows

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\newcommand\arbre[4]{%
\path (#1,#2) node[rotate=#4,inner sep=0pt,above] {\Summertree[3.38*#3]};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray,help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
%\path (0,0) node[above,inner sep=0pt] {\Summertree[3.38]};
\arbre{1}{-1}{1}{20}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]